# Creation of files dynamically through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

so I want to make a batch file that will create multiple listX.txt containing 3 filenames each in a dynamic way, for instance, let's say I have A.txt, B.txt, C.txt and D.txt, the desired output would be two list files, the first one would be a list1.txt containing the first 3 .txt and the second one would be a list2.txt containing D.txt, can this be done? How? I currently have something like this

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (

  ::title
  echo %%~ni>>list.txt
)
PAUSE
```

it will list them all into a single file but I don't know how to create multiple lists dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to count files, calculate the file number and avoid processing the newly generated listx.txt files.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set cnt=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (
  'Dir /B /ON /A-D *.txt ^|findstr /v /i "list[0-9]*\.txt'
) do (
  set /A "cnt+=1,file#=(cnt-1)/3+1"
  ::title
  echo %%~ni>>"list!file#!.txt"
)
timeout -1
```